regarding periodograms, doppler shift, and pulse dopplers
I need to know how doppler shift works exactly for a project.
I am trying to simulate a simplified version of a pulse doppler radar that takes the distance and the velocity of one object.
I have already finished the first part, but I am having problems with the second.
For example, I have a simple sine wave signal $\sin(2\pi ft)$ where $f$ is the operating frequency and $t$ indicates how long the "pulse" signal would be. I am having trouble specifically trying to make a signal model that would represent the "received signal" where the velocity is reflected in the signal.
I am aware of the doppler effect and doppler shift $(2v/\lambda)$, $\lambda$ being the wavelength, but I don't know how to apply it to the signal.
Do I add it to the frequency, as in $\sin(2\pi(f+f_d)t)$, or do I replace the previous frequency with it, as in $\sin(2\pi f_d t)$?
Also, I am trying to make use of periodograms and I have a general gist of how they work. From what I understand, the received signal is the input for this, it returns a bunch of power values, I take the maximum out of all these, and the corresponding frequency value associated with the maximum power value will be used to determine the velocity, is that correct?

Here is a simplified break down. Let the target be $r$ meters away, then the round-trip delay for the transmitted wave is just $2r/c_0$, where $c_0$ is the propagation speed (i.e., the speed of light). Now suppose the target is moving with velocity $v$ and at time $t=0$ its distance to the radar is $r_0$. Thus, at some arbitrary time $t$, the target is located $r_0 + vt$ meters away and the round trip delay will now be
$$
\tau(t) = \frac{2}{c_0}(r_0+vt).
$$
For a transmitted signal defined by $s(t)$, the returned signal is just a delayed version of what was transmitted. Usually, this is given by $s(t - \tau)$ for some fixed $\tau$. However, for a moving target $\tau$ is function of $t$, so the returned signal is give by $s(t-\tau(t))$. If we put this into your sine wave, we get
$$
\sin( 2\pi f t ) \rightarrow \sin( 2\pi f (t - \tau(t) ) = \sin\left( 2\pi f \left(t - \frac{2}{c_0}(r_0+vt) \right)\right)
$$
If we let $\tau_0 = 2r_0/c_0$, then after some manipulation we get
$$
\sin\left( 2\pi f \left(1 - 2\frac{v}{c_0} \right) t - 2\pi f\tau_0\right)
=
\sin\left( 2\pi \left(f - 2\frac{v}{\lambda} \right) t - 2\pi f\tau_0\right),
$$
which shows that the motion of the target affects a shift in the frequency of the received signal.

Hello again. May I ask if it's incorrect for me to use periodogram for this received signal so I can take the doppler shift? I am not sure, but it looks like using this as an input for the periodogram only returns 0 to me, making it look like the target isn't moving.

@survivorfrog Apologies, but I am not sure what you mean. How can the periodgram (which is an estimate of the power spectral density) return a $0$? Are you saying it is zero for all values of $f$? If so, then that can only be true if the input is all zeros. Perhaps you have a misunderstanding of what the periodogram is?

Anon gave a good answer deriving the math. I'll try to provide a bit more intuition to the mathematical model.
Pulsed radars can be thought of through a "stop and hop" model. That is to say, the pulse duration of the radar is usually short enough to where the platform can be thought of as stationary during the duration of the pulse. This means that the platform is taking isolated measurements at different points in time. So, while there is a doppler shift, it is different than say an ambulance driving past you. The doppler shift in radar is a result of the change in the return phase over the course of the CPI. For a constant range $R_{0}$ (0 radial velocity), the received waveform would be
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(2\pi\left(ft-\frac{2R_{0}}{c}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
Notice that there is a constant return phase $4\pi\frac{R_{0}}{c}$. Now, if the range were to change over time, the return phase over time would also change. In the case that the radial velocity is constant, the return phase would be changing linearly. Since frequency is the derivative of phase, we get that there is a constant frequency shift over the course of the CPI.
Now, with radar, you can't use a $\sin$ wave for a mathematical model. $\sin$ waves have ambiguous phase, that is to say there is not one $x$ value for every $y$ value in one period of a $\sin$ wave. This then ultimately means we are unsure of if the target has a positive or negative velocity (real valued signals have two-sided spectrums). The correct waveform you would be looking for is $e^{j2\pi ft}$.
As for the periodogram, yes, that is correct. It spits out what would be considered a bunch of power values, the peak of which is likely to correspond to the speed of your target. There will be some ambiguity as the frequency resolution will be limited by the amount of data you have, but will be accurate to within a reasonable approximation.

Hello, if I may ask some follow-up questions, is the advantage of using the e^j2πft only the positive and negative? If I use the sine wave suggested by anon as the received echo, would I still have the same magnitude for the velocity? If not, may I ask on how to input the e^(j2πft) waveform in matlab? Would it be e raised to everything that was inside the sin function so that it is e^(j2π(f−2*v/λ)t−2πfτ0)?

@survivorfrog Velocity magnitude would likely be the same, but you would have the positive and negative frequency shift. The whole exponent would have to be multiplied by $j$, so $e^{j\left[2\pi\left(f-2\frac{v}{\lambda}\right)-2\pi f\tau_{0}\right]}$.
